# Find if a different array has the same element and open an Alert

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, alert

I know from the question it looks like something that has been already answered on this website before, but please read until the end, because I can't find the answer.

So, I have an Array that contains values of TagsModel:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class DataManager : Equatable, Identifiable, ObservableObject {

static let shared = DataManager()

@Published var storageTags : [TagsModel] = []
typealias StorageTags = [TagsModel]

//The rest of the code
}
```

And the TagsModel:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class TagsModel : Codable, Identifiable, Equatable, ObservableObject  {

    var id = UUID()
    var tagName : String
    var value : [ValueModel] = []
    
    init(tagName: String) {
        self.tagName = tagName
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: TagsModel, rhs: TagsModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id.uuidString == rhs.id.uuidString
    }
}
```

If you need it, the ValueModel is:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ValueModel : Codable, Identifiable, Equatable, ObservableObject, Comparable {

    var id = UUID()
    var name : String
    var notes : String?
    var expires : Date?
    
    init(name: String, notes: String?, expires: Date?) {
        self.name = name
        self.notes = notes
        self.expires = expires
    }
}
```

Now what I would like to do is let the user add the elements of type ValueModel to the array Value of each TagsModel (which in English means I would like users to be able to add values inside their belonging tags). I can do all this, but I would like to add a check: if any other TagsModel contains the value that the user is trying to add, show an Alert (since every value can have only one tag). This Alert should be asking the user whether he/she wants to add that value to the selected tag and remove it from the other one, or cancel the action.

What I managed to do up to now is this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SelectValuesForTagsView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var dm: DataManager
    var tm: TagsModel
    
    @Binding var showSheetSelectValuesForTagsView : Bool
    @State var showAlertValueAlreadyInTag = false
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @GestureState private var dragOffset = CGSize.zero
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                ForEach(dm.storageValues) { valuesOfForEach in
                    HStack {
                        if tm.value.contains(where: { $0.id.uuidString == valuesOfForEach.id.uuidString
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                                .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                        } else {
                            Image(systemName: "circle")
                                .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
                                .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
                        }

                        Button(action: {
                            if !tm.value.contains(where: { $0.id.uuidString == valuesOfForEach.id.uuidString
                            }) {
                                tm.value.append(valuesOfForEach)
                                dm.save()
                            } else {
                                guard let indexValue = tm.value.firstIndex(where: { $0.id.uuidString == valuesOfForEach.id.uuidString
                                }) else { return }
                                  tm.value.remove(at: indexValue)
                                dm.save()
                            }

                        }, label: {
                            if tm.value.contains(where: { $0.id.uuidString == valuesOfForEach.id.uuidString
                            }) {
                                Text(valuesOfForEach.name)
                                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            } else {
                                Text(valuesOfForEach.name)
                                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                            }
                        })

                    }

                }

            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Add Values"), displayMode: .automatic)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: saveButton)
        }
    }
    
    var saveButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            let tag : TagsModel
            if dm.storageTags.contains(where: {$0.value == tm.value}) {
                showAlertValueAlreadyInTag = true


                //The problem is here, that the Alert ALWAYS shows up, even though there's only this Tag containing that value



            }

            else {
            dm.save()
            showSheetSelectValuesForTagsView = false
            }
        }, label: {
            Text("Save")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }).alert(isPresented: $showAlertValueAlreadyInTag, content: { alertValueAlreadyInTag })
    }
    var alertValueAlreadyInTag : Alert {
        Alert(title: Text("Attention!"), message: Text("Every value can only be assigned to one tag. One or more values you selected are already into another tag. Would you like to substitute the belonging tag for these values?"), primaryButton: Alert.Button.default(Text("Yes, substitute"), action: {
            dm.save()
            showAlertValueAlreadyInTag = false
            showSheetSelectValuesForTagsView = false
        }), secondaryButton: Alert.Button.default(Text("Cancel"), action: {
            showAlertValueAlreadyInTag = false
        }))
    }
}
```

How can I check if another tag inside the storageTags has the already the same value inside of its value Array?

Comment: Have you explored using an array of dictionary instead? You could easily enforce a 1 to 1 rule like you are contemplating.

Comment: Could you please explain me more about this or link me to somewhere I can read more about it? Thank you!

Comment: That is a basic type in Swift. See: [Swift.org](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html). Scroll down to find Dictionaries. There are thousands of pages on them.